# Linux Script; For Loop to rename; New to Scripting

Tags: linux, scripting, ksh

You will have to forgive me I have very little experience writing Linux Scripts.  Ok What I'm trying to do is rename part of a file that has a specified name in, but the problem I'm coming across is I get the error during my For Loop is this **0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command** I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my for loop, can someone please assist?

```
    #Creates Directory
    echo "Name of New Directory"
    read newdir
    if [[ -n "$newdir" ]]
    then
      mkdir $newdir
    fi
    echo $userInput Directory Created
    echo 
    echo "Directory you wish to Copy?"
    read copydir
    if [[ -n "$copydir" ]]
    then
    #Copies contents of Specified Directory
     cp -R $copydir/!(*.UNC) $newdir;

    #Searches through directory  
    for file in $newdir/$copydir*; do
    mv -v -- "$file" "${file/old/new}";
    done


fi
```

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing this. I did `mkdir -p newdir copydir; touch copydir/{a.txt,b.txt,c.UNC,e.UNC}; newdir=newdir; copydir=copydir` but how do you expect `for file in $newdir/$copydir*` to work? Where from should the directory `$newdir/$copydir` come / what files should be named in the `$newdir/$copydir` path? Did you meant to copy with full paths? Can you create a reproducible example? Ex. include directories and files creation or post what input do you give to your program and what are the contents of newdir and copydir prior to running the script??

Comment: Agree with comments above, AND error messages in the form of `0403-011 ...err msg` look like something from AIX OS. Is that the case? If so, edit your Q to show the results from `echo $SHELL` (and maybe `echo $BASH_VERSION`). Its possible the shell you are listing at the top `#!/bin/sh` (?) doesn't support the ${var/old/new} syntax. AND better to update your Q and add a  comment like "see updates in Q", rather than create a long thread of comments/code that are hard to read. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of ksh are you using?

`"${file//old/new}"` and `"${file/old/new}"` are valid syntaxes in [ksh93](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh93).

If your env is [ksh88](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105130220/www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh88.html) `"${file//old/new}"` substitution is not supported.

You have to use sed/tr to replace pattern. Here is an example with sed.

`mv -v -- "$file" "$(echo ${file}|sed 's/old/new/')"`

Comment: Thank You, it worked, now just a noob question is it possible to use variables were old and new are in the sed?  I'm just curious. Thanks

Comment: I got it, but Thank You, your Sed command definitely helped me with my problem `mv -- "$file" "$(echo ${file}|sed 's/'$copydir'/'$newdir'/')"`

Answer (score 0):

The offending line:

```
mv -v -- "$file" "${file/old/new}";
```

should be:

```
mv -v -- "$file" "${file//old/new}";
```

If you want to replace `$old` with `$new` (as opposed to the literal string `"old"` with `"new"`), write:

```
mv -v -- "$file" "${file//$old/$new}";
```

Comment: No luck still same error, here is my for loop `for file in $newdir/$copydir*; do
mv -v -- "$file" "${file//old/new}";
done`

Comment: @JoshAdams Then I've no clue. Sorry.